# Reference Error: funcion is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to java-script, so please bear with me. I built a little game to try and practice using javascript, but it's not working. I'm getting an error that says

`"ReferenceError: begin is not defined"` in the console ("begin" is my function).

Here's the submit button in html:

```
<input class="submit" onclick="javascipt: begin();" type="submit" value="Begin!">
```

and here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function begin() {
     /*code*/
  }
</script>
```

The javascript comes after the body of the html and nothing comes after it. I tried putting it in the head, but it didn't solve the problem. I know this is probably a very simple fix, but like I said, I'm new to js.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

edit: if this isn't enough code to find a problem, here is a link to the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/Shbababa/jBKy2/

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but you don't need the `javascript:` prefix in `onXXX` attributes; you only need that if you're putting a script where a URL would normally go, such as `href`.

Comment: Note: If you're basing the question on JSFiddle, the `onLoad` option under "Frameworks & Extensions" on the left is important and does have an effect on scope. Try one of the `No wrap` options instead.

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Pxuey/2/ I just selected `No wrap` from the menu on the left, because `onLoad` puts the function inside another function so it's not in the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

`javascipt:` is both spelled wrong and unnecessary in the code you have given.

It should look like this:

```
onclick="begin()"
```

However, I would strongly recommend against using inline JavaScript.

Comment: How is this a fix to the problem? It's unnecessary, but it won't cause a problem.

Comment: Inside an `on*` attribute, `javascipt:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) rather than a protocol, which can be any identifier. So, the spelling or its presence shouldn't really have an effect.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: @user3708899 You should use what he wrote in the answer, but it won't solve your problem. There isn't enough information to tell why you're getting that error. Maybe you have a typo.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

Comment: @user3708899, does your code come before or after the closing body tag? (`</body>`)

Answer (score 0):

Not a pure Javascript solution, but:

have a look at http://jquery.com
It is easy to learn and Javascript is much easier to write with this little library.

With this, a working example (of many ways you can do it):

**HTML**

`<input type="submit" class="begin" value="Begin!">`

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*  'CSS-SELECTOR' ON 'HANDLER'  'DO SOMETHING' */
$('.begin').on('click', function () {
    /* Code */
    console.log('WORKS');
});
```

});

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ns3HE